# How to delete some rows within a group in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to identify any duplicates between rows of different groups and delete some observation.

My example :

```
data temp;
input siren $ imput $;
cards;
x one
x one
x two
y two
y two
z three
z three
z four
;
run;
```

The output I want :

```
siren imput
x one
x one
y two
y two
z three
z three
```

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PROC SORT for that.

```
data temp;
input siren $ imput $;
cards;
x one
x one
x two
y two
y two
z three
z three
z four
;
proc print;
   run;
proc sort data=temp out=dups nouniquekey;
   by siren imput;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]